# SSRS 2008 Chart series formatting based on expression?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, highcharts, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a chart with a single series as well as a *StripLines* for the average

Chart with single series and StripLines

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRXsA.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Po1.png)

as you can see the values above the Stripline are green and below are red this is done with the following expression under series properties and marker color:

```
=iif(Sum(Fields!Session_Time_Used.Value)/SUM(Fields!Available_Time.Value)<0.68,"Red","Green")
```

what I would like is for <0.68 to be a the same value of the StripLine which is calculated with this expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!Session_Time_Used.Value)/SUM(Fields!Available_Time.Value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can make your chart simpler using negativeColor and threshold parameters:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.threshold
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.scatter.negativeColor

You can calculate your mean value on your load callback function. Then you can add your plotLine and change threshold to mean value:

```
function(chart) {
    var sum = 0,
      ind = 0,
      mean;
    Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
      sum += p.y;
      ind++;
    });
    mean = sum / ind;
    chart.yAxis[0].addPlotLine({
      value: mean,
      color: 'green',
      width: 2
    });
    chart.series[0].update({
      threshold: mean
    });
  }
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmn0fo2e/2/

Kind regards.